# Bass-Serre definition of "split" vs Extension definition of "split"

Tags: group-theory, geometric-topology, combinatorial-geometry, geometric-group-theory

From basic algebra, I am familiar with the concept of splitting in the context of group extensions.  Namely, the short exact sequence

$1 \rightarrow K \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1$

is said to *split* if there is a homomorphism $s : H \rightarrow G$ such that going from H to G by s and then back to H by the quotient map of the short exact sequence has the effect of the identity map on H.

Now, I recently came across another definition of splitting in the context of [Bass-Serre Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bass%E2%80%93Serre_theory).

> An isomorphism between a group G and the fundamental group of a graph of groups is called a *splitting* of G.

**My Question:**  What is the precise relationship (if there is one) between these two types of splitting?

The first implies that G is a semidirect product of K and H.  However (and please correct me if this is not correct), but an HNN extension need not split in the sense of our first definition from basic algebra.  For instance, if the HNN extension of a group G with respect to the isomorphism of subgroups $\alpha : H \rightarrow K$ with $H = K = \{ e \}$, then the usual HNN relation of the form $t h t^{-1} = \alpha(h)$ with stable letter t can be eliminated since $tet^{-1} = e$, so that the HNN extension of the group G would be isomorphic to $G \ast \langle t \rangle$).  But $G \ast \langle t \rangle \not\cong G \rtimes \langle t \rangle $.  However, since HNN extensions are a special case of a graph of groups decomposition, then this would mean $G \ast \langle t \rangle$ still splits according to the second notion of splitting.  Nevertheless, the ideas still seem very related.  Can the first type maybe be expressed as a special case of the second with some restriction on which graphs of groups are "legal" to decompose to?

I would appreciate any insight you guys may have!  Thanks!

Comment: The name splitting for graph of groups is probably more about the topological/visual intuition of the process. Surface groups split as an amalgamated product of free groups, can be seen cutting a surface along a separating curve, literally splitting the space.

Comment: In both cases the splitting means we make some choice of decomposition. Sometimes (certainly not when Serre writes!) there is ambiguity as it can mean there exists a splitting, or that we choose one.

Comment: This is just one of those situations where the same term is used twice in two different ways, there's not too much more to say. 

Still, though, I can think of a certain situation where the two notions are related. Namely, there is a correspondence between extensions $1 \to K \to G \to F \to 1$ where $F$ is a free group of rank $n$ --- all such extensions are split --- and graph of groups presentations of $G$ where the underlying graph is a rank $n$ rose.

Comment: If I could, I would edit my previous comment, changing the final clause to "and graph of groups presentations of $G$ where the underlying graph is a rank $n$ rose and all edge-to-vertex group homomorphisms are isomorphisms". This only emphasizes more strongly the special nature of this situation.